# Dynamics AX 4.0 Export Forms

Tags: export, axapta, x++

I created a method to export AOT (application object tree) Objects.
It works, but when I export the Forms-Treenodes cant find it.

The method is a server method and it runs on a BatchServer.

My idea was to export the objects as xpo files every 2 hours.
By the backup I can track the Code changes.

```
void run(str Path)
{
    List                _ValueList = new List(Types::String);
    Counter             _ListCounter;
    ListIterator        _ListIterator;
    str                 _RootFolder;
    str                 _FileName;
    str                 _FolderName;
    TreeNode            _TreeNode;
    TreeNode            _InnerTreeNode;
    TreeNodeIterator    _TreeNodeIt;
    FileIoPermission    _Perm;
    #define.ExportMode("w")
    ;

    _RootFolder = Path;
    //Objektbaum definition
    _ValueList.addEnd("Forms");
    _ValueList.addEnd("Reports");
    _ValueList.addEnd("Queries");
    _ValueList.addEnd("Classes");
    _ValueList.addEnd("Macros");
    _ValueList.addEnd("Jobs");
    _ValueList.addEnd(@"Data Dictionary\Tables");
    _ValueList.addEnd(@"Data Dictionary\Maps");
    _ValueList.addEnd(@"Data Dictionary\Views");
    _ValueList.addEnd(@"Data Dictionary\Extended Data Types");
    _ValueList.addEnd(@"Data Dictionary\Base Enums");

    _ListIterator = new ListIterator(_ValueList);
    info(strfmt("RootExportPath: %1",_RootFolder));

    // durch die zuvor definierte Liste laufen
    while(_ListIterator.more())
    {
        try
        {
            info(strfmt(@"\%1",_ListIterator.value()));
            //Haupttreenode objekt laden
            _TreeNode = TreeNode::findNode(strfmt(@"\%1",_ListIterator.value()));

            if (_TreeNode != null)
            {
                //Splitten des HauptNodes
                _TreeNodeIt = _TreeNode.AOTiterator();
                _InnerTreeNode = _TreeNodeIt.next();
                //Durchlaufen der SubNodes
                info(strfmt("Object found in Node: %1 ",_TreeNode.AOTchildNodeCount()));
                while(_InnerTreeNode)
                {
                    //Pfad und Filename bereitstellen
                    _FolderName = strfmt(@"%1\%2",_RootFolder,strreplace(_ListIterator.value(),@" ","_"));
                    _FileName = strfmt(@"\%1.xpo",strreplace(_InnerTreeNode.AOTname(),@" ","_"));
                    //Fileperms setzen ("w") = Write (OverWrite)
                    _Perm = new FileIoPermission(_FolderName+_FileName , #ExportMode);
                    if (_Perm == null)
                    {
                        return;
                    }

                    _Perm.assert();

                    try
                    {
                        if(!WinApi::pathExists(_FolderName))
                        {
                            if(WinApi::createDirectory(_FolderName))
                            {
                                throw error(strfmt("Pfad konnte nicht erstellt werden %1\n",_FolderName));
                            }
                            if(!WinApi::pathExists(_FolderName))
                            {
                                throw error(strfmt("Fehler beim erstellen des Pfades %1\n",_FolderName));
                            }
                        }
                        //Export in definierten Filename
                        if(WinApi::fileLocked(_FolderName+_FileName))
                        {
                                throw error("File ist ReadOnly\n");
                        }
                        _InnerTreeNode.treeNodeExport(_Foldername+_FileName);
                     }
                     catch
                     {
                        error(strfmt(@"xpo File %1 konnte nicht geschrieben werden\n",_FolderName+_Filename));
                        throw error("Abbruch des Jobs\n");
                     }
                    CodeAccessPermission::revertAssert();

                   _InnerTreeNode = _TreeNodeIt.next();
                }
                // BP deviation documented.
                _TreeNode.treeNodeExport(_FileName);
            }
            else
            {
                error(strfmt("TreeNode empty %1",_ListIterator.value()));
            }
         }
         catch
         {
            throw error("Fehler in der Verarbeitungsroutine\n");
         }
        _ListIterator.next();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forms can no be exported by a batch-server because the form's ar not loadet.
This ist a litle bit strange but the batchserver calls only class layer in AOT... the Forms ar hirarchical top of it and so on not exportable.

Answer (score 0):

Does the Forms folder exist in your export location?

You are attempting to assert permissions on a folder BEFORE checking it exists and creating it.